# Which one is correct? "greenhouse gases from human activity" or "greenhouse gases by human activity"

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases

Which one is better for the following sentence? I know that "produced by human activity" is more accurate, but I personally prefer to shorten it if it is possible.

> 1. What drives the increase in temperature is the release of enormous
>    extra amounts of greenhouse gases **from** human activity.
> 2. What drives the increase in temperature is the release of enormous
>    extra amounts of greenhouse gases **by** human activity.

The full version is:

> What drives the increase in temperature is the release of enormous
> extra amounts of greenhouse gases **produced by** human activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence, using "from", is the correct option.

1. What drives the increase in temperature is the release of enormous extra amounts of greenhouse gases from human activity.

"Produced by" can't be split up here without it sounding incomplete. Human activity is not an agent that can create something, which is what you would expect from using just "by". However, it can be the source for the gas release, hence "from" is suitable.